# Intel VTune Profiler error for Mac: Cannot communicate with the target

Tags: c++, profiling, profiler, intel-vtune

I'm using Intel VTune on my personal MAC, to profile a remote application on a Linux server. I followed the instructions on https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-vtune/top/macos.html.

When configuring analysis, in the `WHERE` pane, I selected `Remote Linux (SSH)` and specified the `SSH destination` with `username@hostname`. But I got `Cannot communicate with the target username@hostname.`

[image]

I have configured the password-less connection, which means I can directly connect to the target via the command `ssh username@hostname` without a password. I have no idea why it said I cannot connect to the remote target. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: I still have not solved this issue... I notice the second line "**VTune Profiler installation directory on the remote system**". Must VTune be installed on the remote server? Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this without any problem, so I suggest to see possible issues section and follow them, it may help,

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/set-up-analysis-target/linux-targets/remote-linux-target-setup/configuring-ssh-access-for-remote-collection.html

I usually use this command to set the passwordless ssh command, and it works for me:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh remote_username@server_ip_address "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work for me.. From the link you provided, maybe I need an admin privilege to do ssh configuration?

Comment: @Joxixi I also tried again with my windows OS, works, sth wrong with the configuration, in the section SSH Destination you just wrote "usename@server" right? without any extra thing like "the port number" or "ssh" command etc.

Comment: @Joxixi no you don't need to be admin of the target system, I'm not either.

Comment: Hello. I notice the second line "VTune Profiler installation directory on the remote system". What did you fill in it? Must VTune be installed on the remote server? Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Joxixi yes you have to mention the directory of the Vtune that has been installed by the admin on the target (server). once you have been connected to the target, if it could find the path everything is okay, otherwise it will give you another error which says it couldn't find the Vtuen on the target system

Comment: @Joxixi did you solve the connection problem?